# An elegant way to make a 2d array with all possible columns

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy I would like to make a 2d arrray (r, by 2**r) where the columns are all possible binary columns.

For example, if height of the columns is 5, the columns would be

```
[0,0,0,0,0],  [0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1,1], [0,0,1,0,0], ...
```

My solution is

```
 np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat = c))).T
```

This seems very ugly. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as an opinion issue.   Elegance is too subjective. But you are saved by the speed test.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) here, like so -

```
(((np.arange(2**r)[:,None] & 2**np.arange(r)[::-1]))>0).astype(int)
```

For `r` between `0` and `8`, you can also use [`np.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) -

```
np.unpackbits(np.arange(2**r,dtype='uint8')[:,None], axis=1)[:,8-r:]
```

---

Runtime tests -

Case #1 (Original `r = 5`):

```
In [217]: r = 5

In [218]: from itertools import product

In [219]: %timeit np.array(list(product([0,1], repeat=5)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.9 µs per loop

In [220]: %timeit np.unpackbits(np.arange(2**r,dtype='uint8')[:,None], axis=1)[:,8-r:]
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 µs per loop

In [221]: %timeit (((np.arange(2**r)[:,None] & 2**np.arange(r)[::-1]))>0).astype(int) 
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.1 µs per loop
```

Case #2 (Larger `r`):

```
In [242]: r = 15

In [243]: %timeit (((np.arange(2**r)[:,None] & 2**np.arange(r)[::-1]))>0).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.6 ms per loop

In [244]: %timeit np.array(list(product([0,1], repeat=r)))
10 loops, best of 3: 77.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Isn't that in the question?

Comment: @eleanora Ops, totally missed that!

Comment: @eleanora Check out the newly added approaches?

Comment: If you increase r to 20 it is clear that np.unpackbits(np.arange(2**r,dtype='uint8')[:,None], axis=1)[:,8-r:] is at least 10 times faster than the next best in your list and first one is very slow.

Comment: @eleanora But the result won't be correct. That `unpackbits` solution work only with `r` between `0` and `8`.

Comment: @hpaulj The product version is in the question!

Answer (score 3):

Its not numpy but fairly elegant:

```
r = 5
boolcols = [[y&1<<x and 1 for x in range(r)[::-1]] for y in range(2**r)]
```

Some clarifications of the central part could be useful:

```
y&1<<x and 1
```

This is equivalent to

```
(y&(1<<x)) and 1
```

Lets pretend x=3 and y=5 we then get:

1. `1<<x` is `1<<3` which in binary notation is `1000`. A binary one is shifted 3 steps to the left. In python you could write `0b1000` or just `8`. [Read more](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation)
2. `y&(1<<x)` is now `5&8` which is a bitwise 'AND' of `0101` and `1000` which is `0`
3. Now we are left with `(0) and 1` which yields `0`

**NOTE:**
After using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to measure the performance of this against the other solutions, this is not the one you should select to use! Its slower in every tests I have made. Ex:

```
In [21]: r = 15

In [23]: %timeit [[y&1<<x and 1 for x in range(r)[::-1]] for y in range(2**r)]
10 loops, best of 3: 39.8 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit (((np.arange(2**r)[:,None] & 2**np.arange(r)[::-1]))>0).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 ms per loop
```

Comment: `np.unpackbits` solution works only with r less than or equal to 8, so maybe try out the other solutions for benchmarking for r >8.

Comment: Updated the tests (similar result though).

Comment: Well, still not bad this solution :) Thanks for timing those BTW!

Comment: `%timeit (((np.arange(2**r)[:,None] & 2**np.arange(r)[::-1]))>0).astype(int)`
100 loops, best of 3: 2.56 ms per loop  . That does seem to be the fastest option.

Answer (score 3):

Another non-numpy solution:

```
r = 3
print [map(int, list('{:0{w}b}'.format(x, w=r))) for x in xrange(2**r)]
```

Giving:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: `timeit [map(int, list('{:0{w}b}'.format(x, w=r))) for x in xrange(2**r)]`
1 loops, best of 3: 207 ms per loop

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
   np.array([list("0"*(r-1-int(np.log2(i)))+"{0:b}".format(i))  if i>0 else [i]*r for i in range(0,2**r)]).astype(int)
```

**EDIT**

I noticed that it is unnecessary to use log2 calculation in a formatting solution:

```
frmt = "{0:0"+str(r)+"b}"
print [map(int,list(frmt.format(i))) for i in range(0,2**r)]
```

And the time difference ..

```
In [17]: timeit [map(int,list(frmt.format(i))) for i in range(0,2**r)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 171 µs per loop

In [18]: timeit np.array([list("0"*(r-1-int(np.log2(i)))+"{0:b}".format(i)) if i>0 else [i]*r for i in range(0,2**r)]).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 514 µs per loop
```

Comment: `timeit np.array([list("0"*(r-1-int(np.log2(i)))+"{0:b}".format(i))  if i>0 else [i]*r for i in range(0,2**r)]).astype(int)`
1 loops, best of 3: 332 ms per loop

Comment: `timeit [map(int,list(frmt.format(i))) for i in range(0,2**r)]`10 loops, best of 3: 179 ms per loop

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.product` is a fast C code; `np.array` is slower general purpose code.  `np.fromiter` can, in the right situations, be faster.  But `fromiter` requires a flat input, not nested lists.  But another `itertools` does a good job of flattening lists.

Here are some iteresting time comparisons:

```
In [72]: timeit list(product([0,1],repeat=5))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.03 us per loop

In [73]: timeit list(chain(*product([0,1],repeat=5)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 us per loop

In [74]: timeit np.fromiter(chain(*product([0,1],repeat=5)),int,count=160).reshape(-1,5)
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.8 us per loop

In [75]: timeit np.array(list(product([0,1],repeat=5)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.1 us per loop
```

In this case including a `count` win `fromiter` doesn't make much difference.

There is a certain Pythonic elegance in chaining generators.

---

By way of comparison, my time for the pure numpy method is a bit slower:

```
In [85]: timeit (((np.arange(2**5)[:,None] & 2**np.arange(5)[::-1]))>0).astype(int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.1 us per loop
```

But @Divakar shows this solution scales much better.

Comment: For r = 15 I get  timeit list(chain(*product([0,1],repeat=r)))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop timeit list(chain(*product([0,1],repeat=r)))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per looptimeit np.array(list(product([0,1],repeat=15)))
10 loops, best of 3: 44.1 ms per loop
I don't understand the fromiter line enough to know how to set r = 15.

Comment: `timeit (((np.arange(2**r)[:,None] & 2**np.arange(r)[::-1]))>0).astype(int)`
100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loop  This seems to be much quicker!